# Data not showing in rdlc report asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm generating a report using stored procedure; however when I execute I'm seeing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP8SX.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP8SX.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvnKg.png but when I execute the stored procedure there's actually data there to be shown.

Code behind

```
     string strSQLconstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        //report path
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("PP_CountReturn", strSQLconstring);
        adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //object of Dataset DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "PP_CountReturn");
        //Datasource for report
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
        ReportViewer1.Width = 600;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ7eW.png)

Comment: Is this the first time you deploy a RDLC on Webforms/Winforms?

Comment: yes it is my first time

Comment: Aren't you missing the `this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();`?

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo I'm not understanding why the data no showing on the report

Comment: Does the report shows the data in the report designer?

Comment: it was giving this error message Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Comment: data only show when I execute the stored procedure

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed when deploying rdlc reports is that dataset's column names at your code behind must match the ones in the report's `DataSet`. So if your stored procedure changed you'll have to refresh your report at the designer.

Comment: but would that stop the data from showing even  thou the report design comes up https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvnKg.png

Comment: Ok, look, when you desing a report, there's a `Preview` option where you can test your report. Are you able to do that?

Comment: no i'm not see that optin

Comment: Post a screenshoot from your report designer with the DataSource panel visible if posible.

Comment: You gotta make sure your report works before publishing it.

Comment: I've added the screenshots

Comment: What's the name of the report designer? SQL Server Data Tools or the one integrated with VS?

Comment: report.edlc is the name

Comment: I mean the name of the program or tool where you're designing `Report.rdlc`

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: Ok. Now preview your report and post results please: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/previewing-reports?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo; I'm not understanding how to get the preview

Comment: Check the link I provided above, you should find a similar option to verify that the report actually works before pubblishing it on your application.

Comment: This link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/previewing-reports?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: still not able preview don't see anything like that

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I load the `ReportDataSource`:

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();

//...
// Query the database...
//...

reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];

this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: CS1061: 'ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'RefreshReport' and no extension method 'RefreshReport' accepting a first argument of type 'ReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok, you're on webforms, I tought you were on winforms. Does your stored procedure accepts any parammeters?

Comment: The other thing I see different from the code I have for a webforms solution is the base path for the report, I use:  `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/reports/Report.rdlc"`. It's hard to determine what the cause could be. I would also check the dataset's name is actually `DataSet1` at the report designer.

Comment: it is still the same result and it is the correct name